# Start and end time, split into 1 hour segments

Tags: php, strtotime

I have a start and end time in a `timestamp` format. I want to split these into timeslots of e.g 1 hour.

```
$t1 = strtotime('2010-05-06 12:00:00');
$t2 = strtotime('2010-05-06 18:00:00');

$timeslots = array();

while ($t1 < $t2) {
  $t1 = $t1 + 3600;
  $timeslots[] = $t1;
}

foreach ( $timeslots as $slot ) {
  echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $slot) . '<br/>';
}
```

Is this the most efficient way to do it or is there a better, more versatile way to do this?

Occasionally when trying it with other numbers for different length timeslots there was a Fatal error: Allowed memory size exhausted which makes me think it's not very efficient. Though that doesn't appear to be happening now...

(I'm building a booking sytem)

Comment: Do you only need to print them out or do you need to use the "timeslots" for something else later?

Comment: I'll be putting them into a MySQL database, and then assigning bookings to each timeslot.

Comment: Allowed memory size exhausted reports also a line where error occurred. Why didn't you post this line here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried

```
while ($t1 < $t2) {
   $t1 = strtotime('+1 hour', $t1);
   $timeslots[] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $t1);
}

foreach ( $timeslots as $slot ) {
   echo $slot . '<br/>';
}
```

Somewhat the same but cleaner. And as was said strtotime will handle date changes like leap years. What is your PHP memory limit set at? Might be too low.

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 25165824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes).

Comment: Can you try setting php memory limit to 32M?

Comment: I don't have access to that, but it appears to be working OK now. Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

using php 5.3

```
$dateTimes = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime($start),
    new DateInterval('PT1H'),
    new DateTime($end)
);

foreach ($dateTimes as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than

```
$t1 = $t1 + 3600;
```

You'll be better off with

```
$t1 = strtotime('+1 hour', $t1);
```

The latter will adjust to daylight savings time, leap years, etc.

Otherwise, your code looks fine. If you ran out of memory it was probably due to an infinite loop. You probably want to add code to make sure that $t2 is larger than $t1, and to switch them if they aren't.

Comment: Good thinking. That *should* never happen but stranger things have happened.

Comment: Right. Lot's of things that shouldn't happen happen pretty frequently. Also, you might want to check the result of your strtotime() calls. It will return false or -1 (depending on your PHP version) if the input isn't good, which could also screw up your loop.