# Splitting datetime in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I have 2 `datetime` value:

```
$begin = new DateTime( "2015-07-03 12:00:00" );
$end   = new DateTime( "2015-07-04 14:00:00" );
```

and I need to split it to this result:

```
val11 = 2015-07-03 12:00:00;
val12 = 2015-07-03 23:59:59;

val21 = 2015-07-04 00:00:00;
val22 = 2015-07-04 14:00:00;
```

Comment: What do you mean by splitting? What's the logic?

Comment: Actually what do you need, date and time separately? Didnt get what you mean.

Comment: Have you tried something? How about something similar to this question that asks to split a date into 1-hour long segments? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500482/start-and-end-time-split-into-1-hour-segments

Comment: will you please elaborate..

Answer (score 1):

Hi did you have read the manual ?  http://php.net/manual/fr/class.datetime.php

```
$val11 = $begin->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$val12 = $begin->format('Y-m-d').' 23:59:59';
```

With that you should be able to code the complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.add(DateInterval)`

```
DateInterval {
/* Properties */
public integer $y ;
public integer $m ;
public integer $d ;
public integer $h ;
public integer $i ;
public integer $s ;
public integer $invert ;
public mixed $days ;
/* Methods */
public __construct ( string $interval_spec )
public static DateInterval createFromDateString ( string $time )
public string format ( string $format )
}
```

So, you need to add 3 `DateInterval`'s; 7 hours 59 minutes 59 seconds.. then add another second - and lastly 14 hours. Or whatever your logic is, make some math from the hour / minute / second of the `DateTime` and adjust your `DateInterval` accordingly. Each time you add an interval, you print a formatted datetime string.

Answer (score 0):

Values *$begin* and *$end* are datetime from form ($POST). 
I want to show "inputs" and "outputs" with real data.